# RedSHOP - mod_products info needed

Tags: joomla, joomla-module

I'm terribly sorry to post this question here, but RedCOMPONENT just does not bother to answer my forum post or anyone else for that matter.

All I want to know, can this mod_products from RedCOMPONENT display featured products as well as products from a specific brand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with the extension you mentioned unless you code it yourself. I haven't looked into redSHOP majorly before and I;m not going to pay to download the module you mentioned, but in one of the PHP files, there will be some code retrieving the products from a specific table column using an SQL command. You could always try adapting this so that (if features products have their own table column) the SQL command retrieve products from both columns.

Else, you might be interested in this module which shows the features products for RedSHOP.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/redshop-extensions/13964

Comment: Thanks, I think that module is the mod_products that are on their website.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mod_redshop_featureproduct module.